# Display specific WordPress categories on a page without a plugin

Tags: wordpress, categories, shortcode

I'm trying to display a specific category on a WordPress page using a shortcode. I'm familiar with making a custom page template and calling the category there, however my end users will have to be able to add more categories without creating new page templates for each.

Essentially I'm looking for how to create a shortcode that would call a specific category of posts on a page without creating a custom template or using a plug-in.

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask why you want this done using a shortcode? You are aware that you can just add any category as a menu item? For example, adding category xyz as a menu item will bring up the WordPress "archive" page with just posts from category xyz.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example. Modify it as needed.

```
add_shortcode('catlist', function($atts, $content) {
    $atts += array('category' => 1);
    $posts = get_posts("category={$atts['category']}");

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        echo $post->post_name . '<br />';
    }
});

echo do_shortcode('[catlist category=5]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at source code of this plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-post-shortcode/ and you find the solution (approximately 50 lines of code).